# How to edit a config file using the command line?

Tags: linux, bash, gnu

How can I edit a config file in Linux using the command line? For example I would like to update value for `FLAGS_PLATFORM` or get the value.

Here is the file

```
FLAGS_PLATFORM=X86
FLAGS_BUILD_TYPE=DEBUG
```

Comment: Do you know what's in the file?  Do you know where the file is?  If yes to both then you can use sed to do a find-replace in the file like:
sed -i -e 's/x86/${NEWVALUE}/g' /path/to/filename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sed`.

For example:

```
sed 's/^FLAGS_PLATFORM=X86$/FLAGS_PLATFORM=whatever/' < file
```

Comment: But how to get the value for FLAGS_PLATFORM?